# Taking Post data for jquery function from a view in codeigniter using loops

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have the following view in codeigniter- say edit_res_view-

```
<html>
<table>
    <? foreach ($list as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr><td><?= $key ?> :</td><td><input type="text" name='<?= $key ?>' size="25" value='<?php echo $value; ?>'/></td></tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>

    <tr><td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" id="submit" size="40" value="SAVE" />

</table>
```

Now I have another jquery function in another view which takes the values from the name attributes of this form to send as POST data to another function -

```
$("#submit").live("click",function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/codeigniter_local/index.php/manage_resources/doupdate_des",
        type:"POST",                                         
        data:"d_id="+$("[name='d_id']").val()+
              "&cpu_brand="+$("[name='cpu_brand']").val()+
              "&processor="+$("[name='processor']").val()+
              "&ram="+$("[name='ram']").val()+
              "&hdd="+$("[name='hdd']").val()+
              "&mac_id_wired="+$("[name='mac_id_wired']").val()+
              "&mac_id_wireless="+$("[name='mac_id_wireless']").val()+
              "&os="+$("[name='os']").val()+
              "&os_license_no="+$("[name='os_license_no']").val()+
              "&monitor_sno="+$("[name='monitor_sno']").val()+
              "&keyboard_sno="+$("[name='keyboard_sno']").val()+
              "&mouse_sno="+$("[name='mouse_sno']").val()+
              "&sno="+$("[name='sno']").val()+
              "&date_of_purchase="+$("[name='date_of_purchase']").val()+
              "&warranty="+$("[name='warranty']").val()+
              "&comments="+$("[name='comments']").val(),

        success:function(html){

            oTable.fnReloadAjax('http://localhost/codeigniter_local/index.php/manage_resources/json/1');
            alert("Done !");
            $("#form1").dialog("close");
        },  
        ERROR: function(html){                                             
            alert(html);                                        
        }  
    });
} );//for submit
```

Now the problem is that I want to loop through the values for the "data:" attribute of the jquery function instead of hardcoding it, as I have done above.

How to go about it? (btw the $list array is passed as an argument to edit_res_view through my controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work using the [jQuery `map` function](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=map):

```
var postData = $("#form1 input:text").map ( function (J, node) {
    var jThis   = $(node);
    return jThis.attr ('name')  + '=' +  jThis.val ();
} ).get ().join ('&');


$.ajax({
    url:  "http://localhost/codeigniter_local/index.php/manage_resources/doupdate_des",
    type: "POST",                                         
    data: encodeURI (postData)
    ... ...
```

That code assumes that the form has an id of "form1", and helps ensure that only the correct forms inputs are used.

Comment: hmmm..i m a little confused...how does $postdata get values of the input fields from the 'edit_res_view' ? the edit_res_view and the view with the $("#submit").live() code are two different views.

Comment: You said you `"want to loop through the values for the 'data:' attribute of the jquery function instead of hardcoding"`.   You want to do this looping in PHP?!!? ...and still send that unwieldy monstrosity to the user's browser?!!?  Far better to use the JS I showed you (except tune the input selector with details that are not in the question).  You'll have simpler PHP and simple JS, and fewer things to go horribly wrong.

Comment: oops...sorry i was thinking something else...ur code is exactly what i need...but can u tell me how do i select a specific form's input on my page..for example right now i have 2 forms with ids- "form1" and "form2"..how do i apply the postData code for that specific form's input field?...sorry for the noobish query...i am relatively new to jquery... also what is the "J" variable for in the above query...

Comment: I tried the following syntax... var postData = $("form#form1 input[type=text]").map ( function (J, node) {
        var jThis   = $(node);
        return jThis.attr ('name')  + '=' +  jThis.val ();
    } ).get().join ('&');     but firebug's debugger is showing that no POST data is being sent...what's the problem??

Comment: Updated the answer.  It's not clear, do you have 2 of the same kind of form?  But only one submit button is shown getting activated. ... ... `J` is just an index variable. Needed to specify it to get the `node` value (although I could have just used `this` in this case).  I added a link to the DOC, to the answer. ... ... No POST data could be almost anything.  Add `console.log(postData);` to the code; what does Firebug's console show?

Comment: no form1 and form2 are two different forms....basically the post fields are not getting appended to the postData variable....

Comment: its working finally ;)...it seems i had wrongly prefixed form to #form1...changed it and its workin perfectly now...thx a million again for ur patience... ;)